# OpenGL UBO containing big array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, buffer, limits

I've switched from memory wasteful vertex attributes to UBO to use much less memory. I want to create big buffer (containing more than 1024*1024 values) containing data about given model. Next for each model i would leave program and vertex buffer (since mesh is the same) and change UBO for next model. So each UBO would be set once and then only binding changed to different buffer.

The problem is taht i cannot create so big array. Code like this goes ok:

```
layout(std140) uniform someDataUniform {
   int someData[1201]; 
};
```

but code like this crashes:

```
layout(std140) uniform heightDataUniform {
    int heightData[1201*1201]; 
};
```

Is there any workaround to this problem? Creating big bindable buffer with random access by index? Possibly 2D array even (not necessery)?

OpenGL 3.3, GLSL 330.

Comment: use a [texture buffer object (TBO)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture) for large data. The alternative in your scenario could be to directly use a 2D texture.

Comment: is there a way for 2D texture to fetch given texel, like there is a way to do that with Texture1D? And what about performance? Will there be major slowdown UBO vs TBO/Tex2D? And which of these 2 will be faster - TBO or Tex2D?

Comment: `texelFetch()` does of course exist for 2D textures, too. As for performance: You haven't described your scenario, but I guess that you are using this for heightmaps. The internal organization of 2D textures might be even more efficient in this case.

Comment: Exactly, i'm using it for some weird scenario with heightmaps which makes me query once from this texture/buffor per texel (textures) or vertex (buffers). Having textures is beneficient too, since they provide native LoD which i need.

Okey thank you for your help, you might want to sum it up in response and i'll check it as best :)

Comment: @RippeR: `texelFetch ()` doesn't really have "native LoD" (at least not what I think of when I hear it described as such). It fetches texels explicitly without filtering, so that means no automatic mipmapping or anything like that. You can select the texture LOD yourself if you are so inclined - it's rather unfortunate that you are using GLSL 3.30 though, in later versions of GLSL you can use `textureQueryLevels (...)` to figure out how many texture LODs you have. You can figure it yourself if you assume all LODs are defined, given log2 (max (width,height)).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman my "textures" will have constant size so it's not big problem. Also by LoD i ment normal use of texture instead of texelFetch() since height can be interpolated too :)